# Can't enter any commands after starting eth on Windows

Tags: cpp-ethereum, windows, console

I'm running the `eth` client (0.9.41) on Windows 10 using the following command:

```
eth --frontier -b -i
```

as stated [here](https://www.ethereum.org/cli).

The program hangs and I'm not able to enter any commands. The last produced text starts with:
 `"Node ID: enode://e449..., 'setTimeout not available in this environment'"`.

What am I doing wrong?

I found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/132).

The same situation is on Windows 7.

Comment: you need -console

Comment: @user697 I'm getting "Invalid argument: -console" when I run `eth -console`

Comment: @user697 OK, `eth --console` is starting, but it hangs with the same message: `setTimeout not available in this environment`

Comment: I have no clue about the set timeout thing as i'm using Geth instead :(

Comment: added an answer, but just reading the version you use, maybe try 1st to upgrade ?

Comment: @euri10 This is the last version of client available for download. Do you where is the newest version?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases

Comment: Yes you have to upgrade to 1.2.0+ as soon as possible regarding the upcoming homestead fork.

Answer (score 4):

You need to open a console, like that:

```
eth --frontier console
```

The `-b -i` flags don't exist anymore. The docs [really need to be updated](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/45116k/call_to_action_homestead_documentation_initiative/).

**Edit**: And please update your client to [version 1.2.0 or later](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases) as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, the symptoms are the same. I ended up using Geth, it's more reliable for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your router has upnp enabled. If upnp is not enabled, you can use the `--upnp off` option and port forward the 30303 port to your machine by yourself.

Comment: Yes, the port is OK. I'm using Geth at the moment and everything is working fine (more or less).